# Android how to position green circle image?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have black and yellow two different layout(Linear Layout) in-side a relative layout. and want to position green circle image as shown in the image. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What you have tried to do so far? Show us the code of your xml layout

Comment: I am thinking to manage it in java code..at run time i will get the height of black-layout and then position the  green image at run time. to manage it in xml is not possible..

Comment: what is this green circle view?

Comment: It is an imageView..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to use your black layout copy below one another and create a new layout from the top black to bottom black. And put your image to center of this layout.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/black_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/black_top_invisible_copy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/black_top"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/yellow_bot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/black_top"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/black_top_invisible_copy"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/black_top"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:top="dimension"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/yelllow" android:bottom="dimension"/>

</layer-list>
```

use this drawable and set as background for the layout you are using. and try to keep the green circle image in between the colors you get in background.